# Grammar analysis: [We] [two brothers] are responsible for this act. [We] [both] are responsible for this act

Tags: grammar, functions

- We *two brothers* are responsible for this act.
- We *both* are responsible for this act.

—What is the function of *two brothers* and *both* in these sentences?

Are they "appositives" or "subject-complements"?

Comment: Better grammar: We are both responsible for this act.

Answer (score 4):

> [1] *We two brothers are responsible for this act.*
>
> [2] *We both are responsible for this act*.

No, they are neither appositives nor complements.

In [1] "two brothers" functions as **head** of the subject NP "we two brothers" in which “we” is a personal determinative and "two brothers" is a nominal consisting of "brothers" as head and "two" as modifier.

In [2] “both” functions as a quantificational **adjunct** in clause structure.  It is separable and not part of the subject NP, which is just the pronoun "we". That it's an adjunct can be seen from the fact that it is movable: we can have "We are both responsible for this act" with no change in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I will expand on the answer given by BillJ.

Your two examples

[1]  i  *We two brothers are responsible for this act.*
      ii  *We both are responsible for this act.*

cannot both be analyzed the same way.

In [1i], *two brothers* is the [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) of the noun phrase (NP) *we two brothers*. In that NP, *we* is a **determinative** rather than a pronoun. The NP functions as the subject of the sentence.

In [1ii], *both* is a **quantificational adjunct** that is part of the NP *we both*. That NP, which functions as the subject of the sentence, has the **pronoun** *we* as the head. However, *both* can be moved to the position between *are* and *responsible* (*we are both responsible for this act*) so that it is no longer part of the NP, although it remains semantically linked to it.

**Discussion**

One difference between [1i] and [1ii] is that only the latter remains acceptable if *we* is replaced by *they*:

<sup>(The asterisk, '*', signifies that what follows is not acceptable.)</sup>

[2]  i  ****They** two brothers are responsible for this act.* 
      ii  ***They** both are responsible for this act.*

This shows that *we* in [1i] has a special function. According to [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) (p. 374) the words *we* and *you* are sometimes not pronouns, but rather **determinatives** (and are thus called 'personal determinatives'). Here is almost the same sentence, but this time *we* is a pronoun:

[3]  *We, two brothers, are responsible for this act.*

In [3], *two brothers* is a supplementary appositive of the pronoun *we*.

Here is CGEL's discussion in full.

> **7.2 The personal determinatives *we*<sub>d</sub> and *you*<sub>d</sub>**
>
> [5]  i  [**We<sub>d</sub>** supporters of a federal Europe] will eventually win the argument.
>       ii  [**You<sub>d</sub>** students] should form a society.
>
> *We*<sub>d</sub> and *You*<sub>d</sub> here are the determinative counterparts of the 1st and 2nd person plural pronouns *we*<sub>p</sub> and *you*<sub>p</sub> that we have in *We<sub>p</sub> will eventually win the argument* and  *You<sub>p</sub> should form a society*. Like the demonstratives, *we*<sub>d</sub> and *you*<sub>d</sub> mark the NP [noun phrase] as definite, but this time what is expressed in addition to definiteness is person deixis: *we* denotes a set containing the speaker, *you* a set containing at least one addressee but not the speaker. *We*<sub>d</sub> like the pronoun, inflects for case, with nominative *we* contrasting with accusative *us*; the distribution of these case-forms is described in §16.2.
>
> It should be noted that the personal determinatives are exactly parallel to other definite determiners such as the demonstratives and the definite article in, for example, permitting the universal quantifier as a predeterminer. Compare:
>
> [6]  i  a.  ***all we<sub>d</sub>** supporters of a federal Europe*           b.  ***all you<sub>d</sub>** students*
>       ii  a.  ***all those** supporters of a federal Europe*        b.  ***all the** students*
>
> This property distinguishes them from the personal pronouns, which permit *all* only when postmodified: *All we/you who support a federal Europe will win the argument,* but not **All we/you will win the argument.*
>
> In [7], however, *we* and *you* are pronouns:
>
> [7]  i  ***We<sub>p</sub> , the supporters of a federal Europe,** will eventually win the argument.*
>       ii  ***You<sub>p</sub> , the students,** should form a society.*
>
> Here, the determiner of *supporters* and *students* is clearly the definite article, and the NPs formed with the definite article are full NPs in their own right which stand in supplementary apposition to the personal pronouns *we* and *you* (see Ch. 15, §5, for discussion of this construction). One reflection of this difference is that the personal determiners can only be the 1st person plural we and the 2nd person plural you, while all the personal pronouns regardless of person and number occur in the appositional construction. We illustrate this with the 1st person singular *I*, the 2nd person singular *you*, and the 3rd person plural *they*.
>
> [8]                       DETERMINER + HEAD                                    APPOSITIONAL CONSTRUCTION
>     i  a.  ****I president** declare the meeting open.*      b.  ***I, the president,** declare the meeting open.*
>    ii  a.  ****You proponent of a federal Europe***    b.  ***You, the proponent of a federal Europe,***
>               *should support this proposal.*                              *should support this proposal.*
>   iii  a.  ****They poets** are our guides.*                          b.  ***They, the poets,** are our guides.*

Another difference between [1i] and [1ii] concerns the effect of change in linear position. Consider

[3]  i  *We two brothers are responsible for this act.*
      ii  *We are two brothers responsible for this act.*
     iii  *Two brothers responsible for this act are us.*

What [3ii] and [3iii] show is that *two brothers responsible for this act* is a **noun phrase** (NP).

Now consider

[4]  i  *We both are responsible for this act .*
      ii  *We are both responsible for this act.*
     iii  **Both responsible for this act are us.*

In this case, [4iii] is not acceptable, which shows that *both responsible for this act* is **not** an NP.

This is related to the fact that *both* belongs with words such as *all* and *each* in that they are all **determinatives.** According to [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) (p. 102), when these determinations are positioned inside the NP (as in in [4i], then they belong to the subject both semantically and syntactically. But when they are positioned outside the NP (as in [4ii]), then they **semantically** belong with the subject, but function as **quantificational adjuncts** that can be positioned outside the NP. CGEL gives the following examples using *all*, but the same remarks apply to *both*. The reason I'm reproducing the following passage from CGEL is to show how flexible such adjuncts are with respect to linear position, and in particular the fact that they can be placed outside their 'native' NP:

> **Quantificational adjuncts**
>
> A comparable difference [to the case of adverbs]  in position between auxiliaries and lexical verbs is found with certain determinatives, such as *all, both, each* (Ch. 5, § 9.2), that are semantically associated with the subject:
>
> [36]                      LEXICAL VERB                                  AUXILIARY VERB
>             i  a.  ***All** the players **took** a card.*      b.  ***All** the players **had** taken a card.*
>            ii  a.  *The players **all** **took** a card.*     b.  *The players **all** **had** taken a card.*
>           iii  a.  **The players **took** **all** a card.*   b.  *The players **had** **all** taken a card.*
>
> In the [i] versions *all* belongs syntactically and semantically in the subject: it functions within the NP *all the players* and it quantifies over *players*. Such items can be positioned outside the NP, and the [ii] versions show *all* in pre-verbal position. If the verb is an auxiliary, it can follow the verb, as in [iiib] - which is preferred over [iib]. But it cannot follow a lexical verb, as is evident from the ungrammaticality of [iiia].

Comment: Thanks. Movability is a nice distinction. You could also do it with *each*, etc.

Comment: If "both" is an adjunct in [1] ii, then it is not part of the subject NP, which is just "we". Adjuncts figure in clause structure, not NP structure.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I didn't explain that well. I've corrected it; it should be OK now.